# Write a CircularBuffer (swift-nio) to a file in Swift using OutputStream?

Tags: swift, circular-buffer, swift-nio

I am trying to use a `CircularBuffer<UInt8>` from SwiftNIO to store data and once the buffer is almost full dump the contents to a file using an `OutputStream`. Unfortunately, the `OutputStream.write()` method takes `UnsafePointer` as an argument, while the `CircularBuffer` can output `UnsafeBufferPointer` . Is there a way to convert `CircularBuffer` to `UnsafePointer`?

I have tried to extend CircularBuffer with the following code that I am using with success to convert structs to Byte arrays as it was suggested that CircularBuffer is in fact a struct, but I am getting garbage in my output file:

```
extension CircularBuffer {
    func toBytes() -> [UInt8] {
        let capacity = MemoryLayout<Self>.size
        var mutableValue = self
        return withUnsafePointer(to: &mutableValue) {
            return $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: capacity) {
                return Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: capacity))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you have an UnsafeBufferPointer then you can take its `.baseAddress` to get an UnsafePointer.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64120725/how-can-i-dump-a-circuralbuffer-swift-nio-to-a-file-in-swift ? You don't get to evade duplicate-ness by asking the same question again.

Comment: Sorry, matt thought it was deleted already.

Comment: While I agree that a question should be improved (instead of deleted and asked again) I also think that the other question has been wrongly closed as a duplicate. This is not about writing a struct to a file, but about writing the “contents” of that circular buffer structure to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CircularBuffer`](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/blob/main/Sources/NIO/CircularBuffer.swift) is a struct with an internal `ContiguousArray` for the element storage. `ContiguousArray` is also a struct, with internal pointers to the actual element storage.

Your current code produce garbage  because it returns the memory representation of the `struct CircularBuffer` itself, and not the bytes of the elements which it represents.

As a collection, `CircularBuffer` has a `withContiguousStorageIfAvailable()` method which calls a closure with a pointer to the element storage *if such contiguous storage exists.* The closure is called with an `UnsafeBufferPointer` argument from which you can obtain the `baseAddress`:

```
var buffer: CircularBuffer<UInt8> = ...
let os: OutputStream = ...
// ...
let amountWritten =  buffer.withContiguousStorageIfAvailable {
    os.write($0.baseAddress!, maxLength: $0.count)
}
```

But there is a problem: `CircularBuffer` just inherits the default implementation from `Sequence` which returns `nil` without calling the closure. This is a [known issue](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/issues/1215). So the above code would compile, but not work.

A simple way (at the cost of copying the contents) would be to use that you can initialize an array from a collection:

```
var buffer: CircularBuffer<UInt8> = ...
let os: OutputStream = ...
// ...
let contents = Array(buffer)
let amountWritten = os.write(contents, maxLength: contents.count)
```

Comment: So at the moment, there is no option other than copying the contents to an Array and then outputting them :( Thx for your reply.

Comment: @jiko: The internal storage is an array of `Element?`, i.e. of optionals, so there actually is no pointer to a contiguous storage of `Element`s which could be passed to the `write` method (this is discussed in the GitHub issue that I linked to). So you have to extract the elements somehow. Either all together as an array, or one by one as suggested by Matt.

Answer (score 1):

You can also cycle through the elements of the buffer one at a time, though that would probably be quite inefficient:

```
    var cb = CircularBuffer<UInt8>()
    cb.append(contentsOf:[1,2,3])
    cb.append(contentsOf:[4,5,6])
    let stream = OutputStream.toMemory()
    stream.open()
    for var i in cb {
        stream.write(&i, maxLength:1)
        print(i)
    }
    stream.close()
    print(stream.property(forKey: .dataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey) as Any)
```